# Lua scripting errors

Tags: lua, syntax-error

[ERROR] Lua is unable to understand file "darkrp_customthings/jobs.lua" because its author made a mistake around line number 21.
The best help I can give you is this:
There is an opening '(' bracket at line 20, but this bracket is never closed or not closed in time. It was expected to be closed before the '=' at line 21.

Can someone help correct the errors in my code?

The code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2w9jx2kqefu2n0/job%20.txt?dl=0

Comment: please include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: All the relevant code is in that dropbox file.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote something like this (simplified):

```
TEAM_TERRORIST = AddExtraTeam(
    "Terrorist",
    customCheck = function(ply) end
)
```

This is not valid syntax in Lua, where there are no named parameters.

Maybe the AddExtraTeam function expects a table instead? E.g. this is valid syntax:

```
TEAM_TERRORIST = AddExtraTeam{
    "Terrorist",
    customCheck = function(ply) end
}
```

Not sure this is the right solution though, I don't know DarkRP.

Comment: I found out the problem, I was putting the customcheck after the curley bracket not before it, and I had missed out a quotation mark at TEAM_TERRORIST